# How to solve a statement with contradiction evidence?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm trying to solve the statement below with contradiction evidence.

> If $(P \rightarrow Q)$ and $(Q \rightarrow R)$ is true, then $(P
>  \rightarrow R)$ is true.

This is what i've done so far:

> $((P \rightarrow Q)$ $\land$ $(Q \rightarrow R))$ $\rightarrow$  $(P \rightarrow R)$

This is the truth table I created for the statement:
[image: contra evidence truth table]

The truth table shows us that the statement is true since all the valuations in 
$((P \rightarrow Q)$ $\land$ $(Q \rightarrow R))$ $\rightarrow$  $(P \rightarrow R)$ is true.

I'm I doing this the correct way or is there something i'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof *directly proves* the given statement. However, if the task here is to prove the statement by "contradiction", we take the premises $P \rightarrow Q$ and $Q\rightarrow R$, and also assume the *negation of the conclusion,* here, $\lnot(P \rightarrow R)$. Then the aim is to derive a contradiction. Upon deriving a contradiction given the assumtion, we conclude then that if the premise is true, the conclusion must follow: we will have proven the same implication you proved directly.

Can you construct the truth table for $$(P \rightarrow Q) \land (Q\rightarrow R) \land \lnot (P \rightarrow R)\quad??$$

You should find that the proposition above yields a contradiction, the opposite of a tautology (table compliments of Wolfram Alpha):

[image]

and as a contradiction, we now reject the assumption that leads to the contradiction.  We conclude $$\begin{align} \lnot\Big([(P \rightarrow Q) \land (Q \rightarrow R)] \land \lnot (P \rightarrow R)\Big) &\equiv \lnot [(P \rightarrow Q) \land (Q\rightarrow R)] \lor (P \rightarrow R) \\ \\ & \equiv [(P\rightarrow Q) \land (Q\rightarrow R)] \rightarrow (P \rightarrow R)\end{align}$$ That is, we have proven that if the premise $(P\rightarrow Q) \land (Q\rightarrow R)$ holds, then the conclusion $P \rightarrow R$ also holds.

Answer (score 2):

Whe does $(P \rightarrow Q) \land (Q \rightarrow R)\rightarrow (P \rightarrow R)$ evaluate to $0$?
$$(P \rightarrow Q) \land (Q \rightarrow R)\rightarrow (P \rightarrow R) \equiv 0   \tag{1}$$

if and only if
  $$(P \rightarrow Q) \land (Q \rightarrow R) \equiv  1  \tag{2} $$
and
  $$P \rightarrow R \equiv  0 \tag{3}$$
Now $(2)$ implies
$$ P \rightarrow Q \equiv 1 \tag{4}$$
and
$$Q \rightarrow R \equiv  1 \tag{5}$$ 
From $(3)$ we can conclude
$$P \equiv  1 \tag{6}$$
$$ R \equiv  0 \tag{7}$$

$(5)$ and $(7)$ gives
$$Q \equiv 0 \tag{8}$$

$(4)$ and $(8)$ gives
$$P \equiv 0 \tag{9}$$

but $(9)$ contradicts $(6)$. So there are no truth values for $P$, $Q$ and $R$ such that $1$ is valid.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fine way to prove that statement.  I don't know what "with contradiction evidence" means, so can't say whether you have met that requirement.  It sounds like you are supposed to start from premises $P \rightarrow Q$ and $Q \rightarrow R$, then assume $\lnot (P \rightarrow R)$ and derive a contradiction.

Comment: Do you know offhand why the sixth and seventh columns don't contain the same truth values? My first instinct was that the statements were equivalent. Why does the OP need to use the implication (eighth column)?

Comment: sasha - the OP is trying to prove the implication in the eight column, not showing that an equivalence between the sixth and seventh statement. He/she is trying to establish that it is necessarily true that the 7th column implies the 6th column.